# SaltStack returning too much detail

Tags: saltstack

Whenever I run `salt '*' state.highstate`, Salt outputs each module using the following format:

```
service_|-zabbix_server_|-zabbix-server-mysql_|-running:
    ----------
    __run_num__:
        17
    changes:
        ----------
    comment:
        Service zabbix-server-mysql is already enabled, and is in the desired state
    name:
        zabbix-server-mysql
    result:
        True
    retcode:
        2
```

I think this started happening after I accidently ran highstate with an `e` appended to the end like `salt '*' state.highstate e`.

Any theories on how to get it back to the normal output format?

Comment: Highstate output formatting is configured in /etc/salt/master or /etc/salt/master.d/ via several interleaving options.

Comment: @DanGarthwaite Just checked, and those files haven't been modified since August 1st.

Comment: I'm not saying it makes sense.  :)  Give salt-master a restart, if that fixes it file a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highstate output formatting is configured in /etc/salt/master or /etc/salt/master.d/ via several options.  Try setting these and restarting salt-master.

> 22.8.4.6. state_verbose
>
> Controls the verbosity of state runs. By default, the results of all states are returned, but setting this value to False will cause
>   salt to only display output for states which either failed, or
>   succeeded without making any changes to the minion.
>
> state_verbose: True

&

> 22.8.4.7. state_output
>
> The state_output setting changes if the output is the full multi line output for each changed state if set to 'full', but if set to
>   'terse' the output will be shortened to a single line. If set to
>   'mixed', the output will be terse unless a state failed, in which case
>   that output will be full. If set to 'changes', the output will be full
>   unless the state didn't change.
>
> state_output: full

&

> 22.8.1.18. output
>
> Set the default outputter used by the salt command.
>
> output: nested

Comment: BTW - I often use json output with the static option:

    salt \\* pkg.version bash --out=json --static

Comment: I made the changes you recommended, but it didn't make a difference. Still the same output format as above...

Comment: I just ran: salt tungsten state.highstate e   and got back a normal output.  Maybe something being returned is enormous (like the contents of multi-megabyte text file being appended) or something?  To answer any more will require delving into the source code.

Could you try the --out=json --static options on a highstate run and see if anything unexpected is being returned?

Comment: No, nothing weird like that is being returned, and even the simplest of state files return the same thing: http://pastebin.com/FWt6JsHf

Comment: That is certainly the default, python outputter.  I think this happened to me, too, many versions ago.  What version of salt-master are you running?  Do the salt-minions match?  Have you tried restarting salt-master?   I'm heading to lunch right now - good luck.

Comment: salt 2014.1.10 (Hydrogen), yes, yes.